# How to access rails cache inside rack middlware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, rack-middleware

I have some custom middleware that is include at the top of my stack and what i need to do in it is access the rails cache. How can I load/access the rails cache from the middleware without having to load the whole rails app up first?

Comment: I think you are satisfied with answer I had posted and you accepted it , can you please vote my answer up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails on Rack
Rails Application's Rack Object

ApplicationName::Application is the primary Rack application object of a Rails application. Any Rack compliant web server should be using `ApplicationName::Application object` to serve a Rails application. Rails.application refers to the same application object.
rails server

rails server does the basic job of creating a Rack::Server object and starting the webserver.

Here's how rails server creates an instance of Rack::Server

```
Rails::Server.new.tap do |server|
  require APP_PATH
  Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
  server.start
end
```

The Rails::Server inherits from Rack::Server and calls the Rack::Server#start method this way:

```
class Server < ::Rack::Server
  def start
    ...
    super
  end
end
```

Here's how it loads the middlewares:

```
def middleware
  middlewares = []
  middlewares << [Rails::Rack::Debugger] if options[:debugger]
  middlewares << [::Rack::ContentLength]
  Hash.new(middlewares)
end
```

courtsy : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html
and also u can follow : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test, and

```
Rails.cache.fetch('test') { 'A test' }
```

inside of a custom middleware, and it worked just fine.

Can you try that?